# Jquery/css displaying an image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with id="mybutton" and a hidden div with id="mydiv" like in the code below :

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").hover(function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mybutton">Show</div>
    <div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">Hidden thing..</div>
</body>
```

I want "mydiv" to appear even if mouse is over "mydiv"(after hovering at mybutton).

Comment: Why you don't wrap all with another <div> and do the hover on it?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak sorry i forgot to write "#". post updated

Comment: @ronen i can't to wrap all in another <div> i have a much more complex project that do not allow me to wrap those things.. other solution ?

Comment: can you put mydiv inside mybutton?

Comment: @Pete Hmm yes, i guess.

Comment: You can add some conditions to your fadeOut. Have a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a common parent to them and connect the hover to it.

**html:**

```
<div id="parent">
        <div id="mybutton">Show</div>
<div id="mydiv">Hidden thing..</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#mydiv {
    display: none;
}
```

**Jq:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parent").hover(function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2W9b/

Comment: Other solution besides giving a common parent doesn't exists ? Because the project that i'm working on do not allow me to edit and give a common parent to the hover area..

Comment: You can wrap them programmatically by JQuery. Need an example? Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/f2W9b/2/

Comment: This is the same as the @DavidM's answer, just replaced `span` with `div`.

Comment: Yes, and it's one minute older. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Write CSS

```
#mydiv{
    display:none;
   /* visibility:hidden; */
}
#mybutton:hover + #mydiv,#mydiv:hover{
    display:block;
  /*   visibility:visible; */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8x7S/)

You can also use `visibility:visible;` and `visibility:hidden;` instead of `display` property

Comment: This is by fair the simplest and nicest solution. Well put together

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").hover(function(){
       $("#mydiv").fadeIn();
    }, function(){
       $("#mydiv").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside div:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="mybutton">Show</div>
     <div id="mydiv">Hidden thing..</div>
</div>
```

And listen for [mouseenter event](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) on the container div.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your button in a container, like so:

```
<span id="hoverarea">
    <div id="mybutton">Show</div>
    <div id="mydiv" style="display: none;">Hidden thing..</div>
</span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hoverarea").hover(function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4B5b/1/

Comment: In this example you give here if i'm hovering on hoverarea <div> i can see mydiv <div> . But i want only when you hover on mybutton to see mydiv!

Comment: That container should be a span, not a div, so it wraps your button and does not have its own space. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the fadeout() portion of your function, can you check if the mouse is currently hovering over the #mydiv div? If so (such as adding a class on hover to the #mydiv), check it and don't fadeout.

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").hover(function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeIn();
    }, function(){
       if (!$("#mydiv").hasClass('hovering') {
           $("#mydiv").fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $("#mydiv").hover(function(){
        $("#mydiv").addClass('hovering');
    }, function (){
        $("#mydiv").removeClass('hovering');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mybutton">Show</div>
    <div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">Hidden thing..</div>
</body>
```